# Tag [regularity]: what is it for, is it needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

There is a tag [regularity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regularity)  with three uses, apparently with very different meanings, and no tag wiki/excerpt. What should we do about it? My inclination is to drop it completely.

Comment: I'd say go ahead.

Comment: With only three questions with the tag, if we don't know what it's for, and it's not much used, there's no reason to keep it. Unless there's some argument otherwise I'm inclined to remove it from those three questions.

Comment: Yes. To be honest, when I come across a tag with only few uses that lacks a wiki excerpt and a clear scope, I just silently remove it myself without raising the issue on Meta. It does not happen very often, but I did a couple of times. (@Glen_b)

Comment: OK,  thanks, will remove now. ...  Done.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it was *bad* to raise the issue on meta.CV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be agreement that such a tag without a tag wiki and used only thrice, without consistency, should be removed.  And that maybe that could have been done without raising the issue on meta. @amoeba wrote in comments that " To be honest, when I come across a tag with only few uses that lacks a wiki excerpt and a clear scope, I just silently remove it myself without raising the issue on Meta. It does not happen very often, but I did a couple of times."

So I just removed the tag.

Comment: Thanks, will correct!

Comment: Thanks for the work you're doing keeping the site organized & tidy, @kjetilbhalvorsen.

Answer (score 4):

With only three questions with the tag, if we don't know what it's for, and it's not much used, there's no reason to keep it. Unless there's some argument otherwise I'm inclined to remove it from those three questions.